# How to add text at the start and end of each line?

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, highlighting

I would like to add some text at the end of each line. For example, for the input

```
This is a long text that will be split by LaTeX into various lines.
```

I want to obtain

```
This is a long textX
Xthat will be splitX
Xby LaTeX into variousX
Xlines.
```

adding X to each line at the start and end.

Motivation: I want `\hl` from the `soul` package to surround the text with padding, similar to `\colorbox` but with the ability to split the text into lines:

```
\newcommand\myHl[1]{{\Large\hl{\normalsize~#1~}}}
```

(note the spaces around `#1`). However, when the text is split into lines, the highlighted spans do not show this additional margin at the start and end of lines:

`This is a long text`
`that will be split`
`by LaTeX into various`
`lines.`

note the margin at the very beginning and very end, but not in the inner lines. Adding a space at the start and end of each line would add the required margin:

`This is a long text` 
 `that will be split` 
 `by LaTeX into various` 
 `lines.`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\myHlWithoutLarge[1]{\hl{~#1~}}
\newcommand\myHlWithLarge[1]{{\Large\hl{\normalsize~#1~}}}

\begin{document}
    I want the text to be highlighted \myHlWithLarge{like this} and not \hl{like this}.

    \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
    \begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.8cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}

    Normal \verb|\hl|        & This is \hl{short text} here
                             & no margin \\

                             & Now \hl{this is a long text that will be split by LaTeX into various lines} when typeset \\

    \verb|\myHlWithoutLarge| & This is \myHlWithoutLarge{short text} here
                             & left / right margin \\
                             
                             & Now \myHlWithoutLarge{this is a long text that will be split by LaTeX into various lines} when typeset \\

    \verb|\myHlWithLarge|    & This is \myHlWithLarge{short text} here
                             & margin around: what I want \\

                             & Now \myHlWithLarge{this is a long text that will be split by LaTeX into various lines} when typeset
                             & but ugly on the inner\- lines!\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

Comment: your question isn't clear and you have provided no example document. you ask initially for adding text which isn't easily possible in pdftex or xetex (possible through Lua in luatex) but it seems by the end you are asking about adding space which is the standard `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` added to every line. It may be that you just want something like `\begin{quote} this is a long text\end{quote}` that increases the space at the margins?  I could not guess the intention of `\myHl` as it switches to `\large` but back to `\normalsize` before setting any text, and you show no example use?

Comment: Have a look at `tcolorbox` before reinventing the wheel... you can have boxes that do almost everything, breaking lines into paragraphs and even across pages.

Comment: @Rmano Thank you, but `tcolorbox` does not seem to be exactly this.

Comment: oh you are just increasing the strut size in soul's hl so not actually using the \large font anywahere (not that you had mentioned `soul` or how you had defined `\hl` previously:) You should really change the title to ask for space not text (and probably mention soul as it is all about soul, not a general question at all)

Comment: Yes, I found no other way to increase the strut, sorry for the confusion. But the question is not about this, but about the margin in the inner lines :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I intended a general question. Actually I use something like `$\,$` for the left-right margin and not `~` as I wrote here for simplicity. Is adding a space simpler than arbitrary text? If so, then I will change the title.

Comment: for the question in the title (without the complication of doing it mid paragraph) adding space tex provides \leftskip and \rightskip for that purpose, but adding text is basically impossible. If you add extra complications like working with soul and working mid-paragraph, the situation is a bit different, but you are starting from that basic distinction between text and space:-). It is unlikely that a generic solution will work for soul, soul is _highly_ intrusive (and clever) code that does what it does but it needs to be in full control of everything.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! `\left/rightskip` seem to work like `quote` on the whole paragraph, not what I was looking for (see the last row in the table). Probably what I want is impossible. Or maybe I need to mess with the code in `soul` directly, but that would be a different question.